# Change default "Edit" application

Tags: windows-7, context-menu, file-association

When right clicking on a file in Windows - a PNG in this example - I know you can change the default app it opens with, but files such as PNG's also have an Edit option.

Is it possible to change the default editing app? If I choose Edit from the context menu it opens in Paint by default but I would like to edit the file in Fireworks.

Comment: It's possible, but it's a complicated Registry edit in that it requires research to determine the specific hex value needed for the key. For example, to change the default _Edit_ from Notepad to Notepad++ for file extensions, [this](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/blob/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/Notepad%2B%2B/Replace-Notepad-with-Notepad%2B%2B.reg) is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your Default Program to open... Easy.

Add an "Edit" option... Hard.

You have to manually add in a custom context menu for PNG to edit in Fireworks by editing The registry key:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\
```

See: [How to Manually Edit the Right Click Menu in Windows](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/windows-right-click-context-menu/)

Or if you want a program to do it see: [Add, Remove, Edit Context Menu items in Windows 7 / 8](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/remove-click-context-menu-items-editors)