# How to change default "Edit" programs for .ahk file extension in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-registry, file-association

I need to change the default "Edit" program for file extension `.ahk`  to Sublime Text in Windows.

How do I do that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Would the extension need to be opened by any other program? If no, change it's default file association; if yes, it's a bit more [complicated](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/blob/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/Notepad%2B%2B/Replace-Notepad-with-Notepad%2B%2B.reg) of a Registry edit _(the example is for NotePad++, but shows all the keys that would need to be modified)_

Comment: @JW0914 .ahk files are AutoHotKey script files so I think normally doubleclicking would run them.

Comment: If re-opened, this probably becaomes a dupe of https://superuser.com/questions/947208/change-default-edit-application?rq=1

Comment: @Tetsujin While I upvoted your comment because it's relevant, it's not applicable to this question as it's regarding adding a context menu entry that is "_Edit with <program name>_" to the context menu, which isn't what's being asked by the OP. Changing the default _Edit_ for an extension to a text editor is a complicated Registry edit due to the hex value of the program that must be known, as I laid out in my prior comment - to change the default _Edit_, at least one Registry key is required to be modified, if not two: `HKCR\ahkfile\shell\edit\command` and `HKCR\ahkfile\shell\print\command`

Comment: To change the default _Edit_, the simplest way I know of to get the program's [Sublime] hex value is to set it as an extension's default, such as `.txt`, export the registry keys for that extension [`HKCR\txtfile\shell\edit\command` and `HKCR\txtfile\shell\print\command`], change `txtfile` to `ahkfile` within the exported key, and import the key _(key `HKCR\ahkfile\shell\open\command` shouldn't be modified unless wanting `.ahk` files to open by default within Sublime when clicked on)_. IIRC, this has to be modified on an exported key, as the path, not the hex value, is shown in `RegEdit`.

Comment: As mentioned, you'll want to edit the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AutoHotkeyScript\Shell\Edit\Command` registry key. This blog shows how: https://blog.danskingdom.com/Change-the-default-AutoHotkey-script-editor/